# McAfee VirusScan for Mac OS X logs 'getgrnam("Virex")' error every 10 seconds

Tags: macos, anti-virus

Every 10 seconds, something like the following appears in the Mac OS X system log:

```
17/12/2009 14:51:11 com.apple.launchd[1] (com.mcafee.virusscan.ScanManager[20499]) getgrnam("Virex") failed 
17/12/2009 14:51:11 com.apple.launchd[1] (com.mcafee.virusscan.ScanManager[20499]) Exited with exit code: 1 
17/12/2009 14:51:11 com.apple.launchd[1] (com.mcafee.virusscan.ScanManager) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds 
17/12/2009 14:51:13 com.apple.launchd[1] (com.mcafee.virusscan.VShieldEPOInterface[20500]) getgrnam("Virex") failed 
17/12/2009 14:51:13 com.apple.launchd[1] (com.mcafee.virusscan.VShieldEPOInterface[20500]) Exited with exit code: 1 
17/12/2009 14:51:13 com.apple.launchd[1] (com.mcafee.virusscan.VShieldEPOInterface) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution; you don't have a "Virex" group.  Go into System Preferences, Accounts, unlock the dialog, click the plus, and select "Group" from the drop down.  Name it "Virex".

Comment: Are you sure masking the issue is the best course of action?

Comment: The issue is "there is no group"; I'm not sure it's being masked here?

Comment: I think Phoshi is getting at the fact that McAfee isn't/wasn't installed properly. Although, to be honest, I don't know why you'd want to install it! :-)